# vb.net special character in sql query variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to retrieve a dataset from a database using a sql string in vb.net.

Code:

```
Dim sSql As String = "Select * FROM mytable where id = " + propID
Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()

Try
ds = coApp.ConnectionManager.LoadSQLToDs(sSql)
Catch ex As Exception
```

The **propID** variable is a value with '/' in it, like '1/83/42'.
The exception message is: **Incorrect syntax near '/'**.
How can I pass this value in my sql string?

Comment: wrap it in single quotes. I.e. "Select * FROM mytable where id = '" + propID + "'"

Comment: OP: use parameters and that will fix the error. Don't do the string concatenation suggestion, that's a bad practice. Kindly ignore those suggestions and write good code.

Comment: Have you tried putting the variable in apostrophe's like so  "Select * FROM mytable where id = '" + propID + "'"

Comment: using SQL Parameters means never having to worry abiout special characters, data type transforms, sql injection and many other things

Comment: Unfortunately, the `LoadSQLToDs()` is probably fundamentally broken and will force the OP to write horribly insecure code.

Comment: I assume `LoadSQLToDs(sSql)` will take a SQL object? If not, ouch...

Comment: Thanks! I was missing single quotes...A lesson in humility.

Comment: You are missing much much more than single quotes.  Danger ahead

Comment: The lesson in humility will be when someone passes in "1; DROP mytable"

Comment: Could be worse @JacobBarnes . It could be `"1; DROP DATABASE MyDatabase;`...

Comment: Ha, indeed. Not sure why I went with table as the example...

Answer (score -2):

Does the value of `propID` already contain quotes in it? If not simply quoting it should resolve the issue:

```
Dim sSql As String = "Select * FROM mytable where id = '" + propID + "'"
```

If you were to print the variable `sSql` in your code You'd get the SQL:

```
Select * FROM mytable where id = 1/83/42
```

which is invalid SQL.

Comment: NO! This isn't a great idea. We don't know where the value of `propID` is coming from, and that statement you have there is wide open for SQL Injection. **Parametrise** your SQL or use a Stored Procedure.

Comment: So what?The OP just wanted to get the cause to the error and not SQL best practices, obviously a beginner mistake and not a production system, that answer is fine.

Comment: @larnu I  agree that this is a bad idea but this is the solution to the asked question. We don't know where `propID` is coming from but the asker does. If it is not from a user there is nothing wrong with this code, there are definitely better ways to do it but that does not make this open for SQL Injection.

Comment: So what? So **everything**. Providing an answer that is wide open to SQL injection is not an answer. Much like using Duck Tape to seal a hole in your fuel tank of your car isn't. It's an awful idea, and a possible disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: "How can I pass this value in my sql string?" was the question, not "Why is this occuring". Parameterization is the best answer. End of story.

Comment: Best answer would be to tell a beginner how quotes / strings / etc comes into play when passing it via code string concatenations, this is a beginner here. SQL binding parameters are indeed the best / safest / performance oriented answer, but not relevant in this scenario to my opinion. I think things needs to be kept simple. There's plenty of reading material and other SO posts discussing this when OP gets to the next level.That's why I think this answer is good, a reference to best practices at the bottom would make it great. @ja

Comment: Guess S/O disagrees as this is now closed and pointing to a "good" answer. I get your point though.

Comment: @JacobBarnes * LarsTech [Gold vb.net] disagrees  :)